# binding form predefined outside let expression

Tags: clojure

*"Syntax error macroexpanding"* when applying the *quote form* to the *binding form* of *let macro*:

```
(def x '[y 1])
(let x y)
```

How to make it work if the *binding form* is predefined outside *let expression*?

**@EDIT**

By chance I tried **locally** on [this problem](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/36) that asks to fill the same *bind form* in each of the three test cases. I failed below hence came up with this question.

```
(def __ '[x 7 y 3 z 1])

(println
 (= 10 (let __ (+ x y)))
 (= 4 (let __ (+ y z)))
 (= 1 (let __ z)))
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do here but the bindings for a `let` expression go within a vector: `(let [x y])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't predefine the `let` binding outside the `let` form. The 4clojure problem isn't asking you to do that although I can see why you would try to do what you showed (`def`ining `__` to be a literal vector).

What 4clojure is doing behind the scenes here is taking your literal input and macroexpanding forms so that your input is placed where the `__` would be. It's doing something like this:

```
user=> (let [__ '[x 7 y 3 z 1]] `(let ~__ (+ ~'x ~'y)))
(clojure.core/let [x 7 y 3 z 1] (clojure.core/+ x y))
```

and then evaluating the result:

```
user=> (clojure.core/let [x 7 y 3 z 1] (clojure.core/+ x y))
10
```

4clojure is expecting that literal vector, without the quote.